# Adding comments to the post with Dajax Django.

Tags: django, dajaxice

I want to add comment to the post by dajax technology in django, but this stuff doesn't work. Could you help me with that or tell a litle bit more how to use dajax in that example.

ajax.py

`@dajaxice_register`

`def add_comment(request):`

```
`if request.method == 'POST':
    post_id = request.POST['post_id']    
    post_obj = Post.objects.get(id = post_id)
    error = {}
    iweb_obj = post_obj.topic.iweb  
    content = request.POST['content']
    img = request.POST['img']       
    if len(content) == 0:
        error[content] = 'Write something'
    else:
        new_comment = Comment(img=img, post=post_obj, content=content, author=request.user, pub_date=datetime.datetime.now())        
        new_comment.save()

        comment = render_to_response('comment.html',{'comment':new_comment})
        dajax = Dajax() 
        dajax.assign('#post-' +int(post_id)+ ' comments', innerHTML, comment)   
        return dajax.json() `
```

HTML post code where comments should be added underneath.

`table width="100%" id="post-{{ post.post.id }}"`

post is here

`ul class="comments"
{% include "comments.html" %}
/ul`

`/table`

JS code, but comment_form is in another template.

`$('.comment_form form').submit(function() {`

```
    `var form = $(this);

    if($('textarea', form).val().length > 1) {
            Dajaxice.project.add_comment(Dajax.progress,{});
            $('textarea', form).val('');

                }
            }

     )});`
```

Answer (score 0):

Some actual error messages would be of assistance - "this stuff doesn't work" is sort of a match for the cryptic Dajax error message "something goes wrong", but maybe there's some additional info you could provide.

I did notice that your js submit function has :

```
Dajax.progress   // which should be Dajax.process
```

Firebug or Chrome's console should help you pick up errors like that

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see exactly what is going wrong without looking at your full code, but from what you've shown above, there are several problems I can see:

1. You shouldn't use `render_to_response` to generate the value of `comment`. Unlike normal Django views, where you are returning an HttpResponse, here you are using `Dajax.assign` to set the actual contents of an HTML element to a string. Luckily Django provides just the template rendering function you need: `render_to_string`. Use that instead.
2. In the `Dajax.assign` line, the selector you are using, e.g. `'#post-23 comments'` doesn't look like it corresponds to the HTML, where `comments` is a class not an element name.
3. In the same line, `innerHTML` should be `'innerHTML'` (i.e. quoted).
4. As toasterleavings mentions, `Dajax.progress` should be `Dajax.process`.

For an annotated example of using Dajaxice/Dajax in a similar way, you may find my answer to [Django and Ajax - What can I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711687/django-and-ajax-what-can-i-do/11715295#11715295) helpful.