# Django and Ajax - What can I do?

Tags: ajax, django

I'm almost done with my site except for the last part where I need to make the gallery page support ajax to change the page number using Ajax.

Gallery pages view:

```
def gallerypages(request, page):
    items = Example.objects.all().order_by('-pk')
    categories = Categorie.objects.all()

    paginator = Paginator(items, 12)

    try:
       itemsList = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
       itemsList = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
       itemsList = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    if items.count()>1:
       return render_to_response('gallery.html', {'items': itemsList,'categories': categories,}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Dajax/Dajaxice are not very well documented... I only need to show some images.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how to do it with Dajax/Dajaxice, which are meant to make AJAX easy in Django:

1. Install [Dajaxice](http://docs.dajaxproject.com/dajaxice/installation.html#installing-dajaxice) and [Dajax](https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajax/wiki/installation) per the documentation. The docs don't seem to mention it, but you can also use `pip`, i.e.

   ```
   pip install django-dajaxice
   pip install django-dajax
   ```

   to the get the libraries. In any case, make sure to follow the doc instructions to install the Django apps and get the necessary Javascript libraries loaded into `gallery.html`. (Note you need to have jQuery or a similar JS framework installed for Dajax to work.)
2. In `gallery.html`, isolate the section where the `items` and `categories` are rendered into HTML. Copy this section into a separate Django template called, say, `gallery_content.html` and then replace the section in `gallery.html` with a blank `<div>` with a specific id, e.g.

   ```
   <div id="gallery-content"></div>
   ```

   What you are doing is creating `#gallery-content` as a placeholder for the HTML that will be generated later for each page via a Dajaxice call.
3. Now, elsewhere in `gallery.html`, create a way for the user to tell you what page to go to, e.g.

   ```
   <input id="page-number">
   <button onclick="Dajaxice.myapp.gallerypages_content(Dajax.process, {'page': document.getElementById('page-number').value})">Go to page</button>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
   ```

   The Javascript `onclick` code -- which is called whenever the user clicks on the button element -- does two things: (1) grabs the value of the `#page-number` input element, and (2) sends it to the Django `gallerypages_content` view asynchronously, i.e. without a normal web browser page load, via the `Dajaxice.myapp.gallerypages_content` Javascript call. Note that `myapp` should be replaced with the name of your Django app.
4. Finally, you need to create the `gallerypages_content` view -- which is a variant of your existing `gallerypages` view modified to work with Dajaxice/Dajax. Dajaxice is hard-coded to look for such views in `ajax.py`, so create `ajax.py` in your `myapp` folder as follows:

   ```
   from django.template.loader import render_to_string
   from dajax.core import Dajax
   from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register

   @dajaxice_register
   def gallerypages_content(request, page):

       page = int(page)

       # ... code to calculate itemsList and categories as before ...

       html = render_to_string('gallery_content.html',
                               {'items': itemsList,'categories': categories,}, 
                               context_instance = RequestContext(request))
       dajax = Dajax()
       dajax.assign('#gallery-content', 'innerHTML', html)
       return dajax.json()
   ```

   This is what the code above does: (1) converts the `page` parameter, which is now a string (i.e the raw string value of the `#page-number` input element), into a Python integer; (2) does the same calculation as before to get `itemsList` and `categories`; (3) uses `render_to_string` to render `gallery_content.html` to an HTML string instead of to the normal Django HTTP response; (4) uses the Dajax API to create an instruction to inject the HTML into the `#gallery-content` div; (5) and, as the view's response, returns these instructions in JSON format. The Dajaxice call in the `onclick` handler will in effect receive these instructions and act on them (strictly speaking, it's the `Dajax.process` callback that does this), causing the HTML to show up. Note that you need to decorate `gallerypages_content` with `@dajaxice_register` -- that helps Dajaxice hook everything together.

I haven't tested any of this specifically, but it's based on how I've gotten Dajaxice/Dajax to work for me and I hope it works for you -- or at least gets you started!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand better now what I suppose to do. I still have 1 issue, I keep getting a js alert box saying "Something goes wrong". I set up the handlers and loggers for Dajaxice, I got this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/dajaxice/core/DajaxiceRequest.py", line 181, in process
    response = '%s' % thefunction(self.request, **argv)

TypeError: gallerypages() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

response: DAJAXICE_EXCEPTION

Any idea of what is wrong ? The functions takes a request and a page parameter.

Comment: Oops, I wrote the `onclick` call to Dajaxice incorrectly. I've (hopefully) fixed it; try it again.

Comment: Hmmm, you mean the approach in my code above is deprecated? From what I can see [here](https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajax/wiki), it looks like the standard way to go. Perhaps I'm looking at the wrong version?

Comment: see here [their link](http://docs.dajaxproject.com/dajaxice/create-my-first-dajaxice-function.html) `Since django-dajaxice 0.2 callbacks must be JS functions and not strings.` and `String callbacks are deprecated since django-dajaxice 0.2`

Comment: Right, my approach is NOT using the deprecated string callback approach. The part that is being deprecated in the line `onclick="Dajaxice.example.myexample('my_js_callback');"` is `'my_js_callback'` -- which should be a Javascript function, not a string name of a Javascript function. And indeed that's what my code above does: it passes `Dajax.process` which is a helper callback function provided by Dajax so you don't have to create your own Javascript callback at all.

Comment: Note the documentation you are looking at is only for Dajaxice, which is the lower-level package that handles the JS/Python plumbing for AJAX. Dajax is the additional package that makes it more convenient to use Dajaxice in both directions -- i.e. with the `Dajax.process` callback, used in point 3 in my answer, for JS-to-Python and the Dajax() class, used in point 4 in my answer, for Python-to-JS.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14637/discussion-between-ghopper21-and-n0idea)

Answer (score 1):

> Should I use django-dajax or django-dajaxice?
>
> In a word, No. I created these projects 4 years ago as a cool tool in
>   order to solve one specific problems I had at that time.
>
> These days using these projects is a bad idea.

https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajax/