# django search using jquery keyup

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

Iam using jquery keyup function for search functionality.I used to view the searched contacts in template.My views as:

```
def contacts_profile(request, search_id=None):
    contact = Invitation.objects.filter(send_visitid = request.user.username, accept_status = True,from_user__username__icontains = search_id)
    results = [ x.from_user.username for x in contact ]
    json = simplejson.dumps(results)
    return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='application/javascript')
```

my django template as:

```
<div id="contact_image">
    {% for contact in contacts %}
        {% if contact.from_user.image  %}
            <img src="/site_media/{{contact.from_user.image}}" id="{{contact.from_user.id}}" onclick="profile(this.id)" alt="" style="border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; width:50px; height:50px;"/>{{contact}}<br><br>
        {% else %}
            <img src="/site_media/img/contact-img.png" alt="" />{{contact}}<br><br>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>

<div><input type="text" class="form-text" name="search_field" id="id_search_field" placeholder="Search Contacts here" />
```

Kindly help me to view the searched contacts in this template in the ajax as:

```
$("#id_search_field").keyup(function () {
        var a =($('#id_search_field').val());
        alert(a);
        var html_str = ""
        $.ajax({
            "type"      : "GET",
            "url"       : "/profile_information/contacts_profile/" +a+ "/",
            "dataType"  : "json",
            "cache"     : false,
            "success"   : function(json) {
                alert(json)
                    }
                });     
         });
```

Help me to view the json values in template.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Dajaxice/Dajax. See the [docs](http://www.dajaxproject.com/) (and [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711687/django-and-ajax-what-can-i-do/11715295#11715295)) for a sense of how it works. Basically you get both a wrapper for (1) making the AJAX call more seamless and (2) for being able to easily program HTML-modifying instructions, e.g. "put this HTML into that div" or whatever, into your AJAX response.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think your jquery ajax is a bit faulty: instead of:

```
$.ajax({
   "type"      : "GET",
   "url"       : "/profile_information/contacts_profile/" +a+ "/",
   "dataType"  : "json",
   "cache"     : false,
   "success"   : function(json) {
        alert(json)
    }
});
```

Use:

```
$.ajax({
   type      : "GET",
   url       : "/profile_information/contacts_profile/" +a+ "/",
   dataType  : "json",
   cache     : false,
   success   : function(json) {
        //see below for the json object
    }
});
```

Then to actually convert the response object to json, do

```
json = eval(json);
```

That way you can have json.<property> calls